# If I run this command, will my Apache2 still work?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, unix

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Basically I just want to turn on gzip for Apache2.

**I don't want to break anything!! Please, tell me that nothing will break when I run these commands.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you've almost got it, you want to do

```
cd /etc/apache/mods-enabled
sudo ln -s ../modes-available/deflate.load deflate.load
```

or you can use `a2enmod deflate`

Comment: I can just type a2enmod deflate, in my terminal?

Comment: And if you run into a problem do "sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/deflate.load" followed by the restart line to return it to normal.

Comment: @alex: You need to sudo, but yep that's all.

Comment: Literally, typing "sudo a2enmod deflate" and everything will work?

Comment: @Alex: yep. oh sorry, forgot to put in my post - still need to do the reload/restart/graceful restart after that command.

Answer (score 2):

1. May be better substitute "restart" with "reload"?
2. Nobody can tell "nothing will break" without knowledge of all details.